# prove that the number of bits for integer number m satisfies the bound, (log_2_(m+1))-1<=k<=log_2_(m)

Tags: algorithm, math

How to prove that the number of bits for integer number m satisfies the bound,

```
(log_2_(m+1))-1<=k<=log_2_(m)
```

The complexity of the integer number is roughly its algorithm base 2.

We may need to represent a number in binary form, like a number x,

[The form img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLRl1.png)

Comment: How does this work for m=0? And for m=1 the only possible value for k is 0 (0 bits??)

Answer (score 2):

Think first at the more familiar base-10 (decimal) representation of positive integers.

With 2 decimal digits, for example, you can write all numbers `10 <= n < 100`. In general, with `k` decimal digits you can write all numbers `10^(k-1) <= n < 10^k`. Since `log10` is monotonically increasing, this is equivalent to `k-1 <= log10(n) < k`, or `log10(n) < k <= log10(n) + 1`.

Now follow the same reasoning for bits, which are the base-2 (binary) digits.